# The operator calculation of Helmholtz equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, group-theory, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am reading the **beam propagation method(BPM)** in optical imaging paper. I find a paper solve the **Helmholtz equation** in the **inhomogeneous media**. The paper is:

[*Light propagation in graded-index optical fibers(M. D. Feit and J. A. Fleck, Jr*](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-17-24-3990&id=22615)

They use the **operator form** to solve the equation, I never see this kind of operator calculation to solve the classical eletromagnetic problem before.  I can intuitively understand what is going on. But I want to learn more about this and acquire such method. However, i am not a mathmatical stduent. **I don't want to learn a full book of the function analysis or some group theory to just acquire this**. I mean is there some good,**simple and not very long pages reading material** to learn this kind of technique.

Besides, there are some places that i don't understand in the paper.

1. Question 1:

Like the equation (3)
[image]

How to obtain this? Now the the expansion for $(1+x)^{1/2}$ is not hold for the Laplacian operator?

2. The second place i don't understand is:

[image]

Why it is equivalent to the Helmholtz equation? Intuitively, I know that using the angular spectrum to solve the Helmholtz equation, we can get maybe the top solution. However, is there or mathmatical derivation of this? From top to expression to the equation (10). Thank you very much

Comment: Roughly: You can treat an operator as a scalar if it commutes with all other terms. Eg $F(\nabla^2 )G(\nabla^2 )\psi (x) =G(\nabla^2 )F(\nabla^2 )\psi (x) $ for not too singular $F,G,\psi$

Comment: Thank you. Make sense. I don't know what does the square root of the Laplacian operaor mean?

Comment: Think about it as the action of the operator on an eigen function (a  sine or a cosine) and then you can manipulate $\Omega$ instead of $\nabla$.

Comment: Sorry what is $\Omega$. Is it the eigen value?  You mean that for example, the Helmholtz equation can be written as a eigenvalue problem $\nabla^2 \phi = \lambda \phi $. The general solution of function $\phi$ would be something like sin or cos term. The $\lambda$ would be something like $n\pi/a$. Then the sqaure root of Laplacian operator mean that the sqaure root of $\lambda$? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I am very interested to know what book or material(like paper tutorial) you learn these operator calculation for the physics problem? Is there some easy-to-learn book for some non-mathmatical student which is not filled of proof things. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a specific reference, What I mean is that by applying an formal function $F(\nabla,  a,b,c\cdots)$  to (say) $e^{i(k x)}$ you will recover $F(ik,  a,b,c\cdots)$.  Where $a,b,c,\cdots$ are constants.

Comment: So this from gradient operator to the ik is depend on the applying function?  And i am very interested in how you learn these technique? I also want to acquire it. It looks very interesting. Thank you.